# I'm trying to set JAVA_HOME and path for JDK on Linux using .bashrc. But it says [ Error writing .bashrc: Permission denied ]. Why?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtual-machine, java-home

I'm trying to set JAVA_HOME and path for JDK on Linux using .bashrc (through [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bEaWqHIuc4w) tutorial):

**Step 1:**

```
$ nano .bashrc
```

[image]

[Press Enter]

**Step 2:**

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

[image]

**Step 3:**

[Type Ctrl+x]

[image]

**Step 4:**

[Type Y]

[image]

**Step 5:**

[Type Enter] (According to this [post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/52461/how-to-save-and-exit-nano-bash-profile-in-terminal))

[image]

As you can see, it is not allowing me to write .bashrc. What could I be doing wrong? I've researched similar errors but none have the same situation I am in. I would appreciate your experience and knowledge in this subject. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to create a new file in the root directory `/`, where a normal user doesn't have permission to write. The file you must edit is located in your home directory, so open the editor this way: `nano ~/.bashrc`

Answer (score 0):

Use `sudo` instead.
This might help you:

```
sudo nano ~/.bashrc
```